# Can I map a decimal property to a float db column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm writing a .NET web app on top of a existing DB app (SQL server).  The original developer stored money in `float` columns instead of `money` or `decimal`.  I really want to use `Decimal` inside my POCOs (especially because I will be doing further operations on the values after I get them).

Unfortunately, I cannot touch the DB schema.  Is there a way to still use `Decimal` in my POCOs and tell EF "It's ok, I know `decimal` and `float` don't get along.  I don't like it either.  Just do your best."

With no special configuration, I get this error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Double' type to the 'System.Decimal' type is not valid.

I tried using `modelBuilder.Entity(Of myPocoType).Property(Function(x) x.MoneyProperty).HasColumnType("float")`, but that gets me this error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
(195,6) : error 0063: Precision facet isn't allowed for properties of type float.
(195,6) : error 0063: Scale facet isn't allowed for properties of type float.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Entity Framework Code First map floats in C# be to decimals in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221227/can-entity-framework-code-first-map-floats-in-c-sharp-be-to-decimals-in-sql-serv)

Comment: What about using views to avoid ugly workarounds?

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić I have read-only access to the DB.  There's lots of data in it and they don't want my changes to "accidentally" break anything.

Comment: This is one more reason to use views here. You can even somewhat control the conversion in your SQL Server views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```cs
public class MyPocoType
{
    public float FloatProp { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal DecimalProp
    {
        get
        {
            return (decimal)FloatProp;
        }
        set
        {
            FloatProp = (float)value;
        }
    }
}
```

EF will ignore the `decimal` one, but you can use it and it'll set the underlying `float`. You can add in your own logic for handling the loss of precision if there's anything special you want it to do, and you might need to catch the cases where the value is out of range of what it's being converted to (`float` has much larger range, but `decimal` has much greater precision).

It's not a perfect solution, but if you're stuck with `float`s then it's not going to get much better. A `float` is inherently a little fuzzy, so that's going to trip you up somewhere.

If you really want to get complex, you could look at keeping the decimal value internally and then using the various events that happen at save time (some logic in an overridden `SaveChanges()`, or catching the `SavingChanges` event perhaps) to convert to `float` only once, to cut down on the buildup of conversion errors.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid cluttering my POCOs with store-specific properties.  There's no way to accomplish this exclusively within the `DbContext`?

Comment: I guess you could override some methods so that when you retrieve these objects you pull the values off them and create instances of objects that have `decimal` properties instead, and then when saving it does the reverse. Depending on the structure of your data access layer this may be non-trivial, requiring changes in many places. My advice: refactor your data access to always go through one method each way (probably `Set<T>()` when reading and `Set<T>().Add()` when saving) and then you can keep your `float`/`decimal` conversion logic confined to those two. A little ugly, but it should work.